# Filter javascript objects array based on a multivalue object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

Need to filter array based on a filter object having multiple values consisting arrays

```
    var vendors = [
      {
        vendor_name: "John",
        region: ["APAC", "UKDE"],
        scanned_status: "Yes",
        channel: ["FILE", "API"],
        pii_attributes: ["A", "B"]
      },
      {
        vendor_name: "Onir",
        region: ["APAC", "LATAM"],
        scanned_status: "No",
        channel: ["FILE"],
        pii_attributes: ["A", "C"]
      },
      {
        vendor_name: "Suresh",
        region: ["UKDE", "NA"],
        scanned_status: "Yes",
        channel: ["API"],
        pii_attributes: ["C", "B"]
      }
    ];

    var filterCriteria = {
      region: ["APAC", "LATAM"], // 'APAC', 'LATAM', 'NA', 'UKDE'
      channel: ["API"], // 'API', 'FILE'
      attributes: ["A", "B"],
      scan_status: "Yes" // 'Yes', 'No', 'All'
    };
    let filtered_vendors = [];
    var result = vendors.filter((el, index, arr) => {
      if (
        filterCriteria["region"].includes(el["region"]) &&
        filterCriteria["channel"].includes(el["channel"]) &&
        filterCriteria["attributes"].includes(el["pii_attributes"])
      ) {
        filtered_vendors.push(el);
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });

    console.log(result);
    console.log(filtered_vendors);
```

But I am not able to apply multiple iteration at the filter level for including the elements. WOuld like to know efficient way to filter the array.

Comment: Does (for example) `filterCriteria.region` have to include *all* values from `vendors[].region` or *any* of them?

Comment: any of them will work.

Comment: look at 'some()' 
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/some

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a dynamic approach by using same keys for `filterCriteria` as well.

This approach checks if the filter value is an array and iterates the values and checks with includes.

If no array then it compares the value directly.

```js
var vendors = [{ vendor_name: "John", region: ["APAC", "UKDE"], scanned_status: "Yes", channel: ["FILE", "API"], pii_attributes: ["A", "B"] }, { vendor_name: "Onir", region: ["APAC", "LATAM"], scanned_status: "No", channel: ["FILE"], pii_attributes: ["A", "C"] }, { vendor_name: "Suresh", region: ["UKDE", "NA"],
scanned_status: "Yes", channel: ["API"], pii_attributes: ["C", "B"] }],
    filterCriteria = { region: ["APAC", "LATAM"], channel: ["API"], pii_attributes: ["A", "B"], scanned_status: "Yes" },
    filters = Object.entries(filterCriteria),
    result = vendors.filter(o => filters.every(([k, value]) => Array.isArray(value)
        ? value.some(v => o[k].includes(v)) // change to every if all have to match
        : o[k] === value
    ));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "term_id": 5,
    "type": "car"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "term_id": 3,
    "type": "bike"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "term_id": 6,
    "type": "car"
  }
];

var result = data.filter(function(v, i) {
  return ((v["term_id"] == 5 || v["term_id"] == 6) && v.type == "car");
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

I had to interpret your question a little. So, in the following code, we check if for every filter if **all** elements of the filter property value are also in the given vendor object property (basically a subset operation). In case you meant **any** element for every filter you need to use an intersection operation.

To implement this, we can use `reduce` for the iteration and sum up individual checks with `&&` (function `isSupersetOf`). To apply this for every filter property, we can apply the same technique on the entries set (function `isMatch`).

Note that I also had to adjust the property names for this to work.

**Code:**

```js
var vendors = [
      {
        vendor_name: "John",
        region: ["APAC", "UKDE"],
        scanned_status: "Yes",
        channel: ["FILE", "API"],
        pii_attributes: ["A", "B"]
      },
      {
        vendor_name: "Onir",
        region: ["APAC", "LATAM"],
        scanned_status: "No",
        channel: ["FILE"],
        pii_attributes: ["A", "C"]
      },
      {
        vendor_name: "Suresh",
        region: ["UKDE", "NA"],
        scanned_status: "Yes",
        channel: ["API"],
        pii_attributes: ["C", "B"]
      },
      // Add a match for illustration
      {
        vendor_name: "Denep",
        region: ["APAC", "LATAM", "NA"],
        scanned_status: ["Yes"],
        channel: ["API"],
        pii_attributes: ["A", "B", "C"]
      }
    ];

    const filterCriteria = {
      region: ["APAC", "LATAM"], // 'APAC', 'LATAM', 'NA', 'UKDE'
      channel: ["API"], // 'API', 'FILE'
      pii_attributes: ["A", "B"],
      scanned_status: ["Yes"] // 'Yes', 'No', 'All'
    };
    const isSupersetOf = (subset, superset) => 
      subset.reduce((result, next) => result && superset.includes(next), true);
    const isMatch = (filter, element) => 
      Object.entries(filter)
        .reduce((result, [property, values]) => result && isSupersetOf(values, element[property] || []), true)
    
    const filteredVendors = vendors.filter((el, index, arr) => 
      isMatch(filterCriteria, el))

    console.log(filteredVendors);
```